# What happens when I use stop command without any args?

Tags: linux, bash

I just accidentally typed stop instead of exit in a bash script. When I execute it my Xubuntu went to the login screen and when I logged in, everything was closed and it was like I just started the computer. 
I then went to my Ubuntu on a virtual box and executed stop in the terminal. Then some windows was closed and some frames around other windows disappeared.

I'm a Linux noob but when I looked at the stop command info it looks like you need to have an argument to use the stop command.
Is this just a bug or is this supposed to happen? If it's supposed, then I'm really curious of whats happening. My guessing is that it will try to kill all ongoing processes.

I'm new here so I hope this it not a stupid question and its really hard to google on a common word like stop :/

Comment: `stop` does not exist on my Linux system. Try `man stop` and `which stop` to understand what it could mean on yours. And your question is off-topic here on SO. Ask it on http://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `stop` belongs to upstart and is used to stop services, like `service XXX stop`

Answer (score 2):

`man stop` should tell you what it does. E.G. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/stop.8.html
I think it *should* tell you it needs an argument for a name of a job to stop.

However it appears from what you describe that it's stopping the X11 window manager?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I did it on my computer with xubuntu then the computer reboot. When I did it in virtual box with ubuntu then some windows closed and some frames disappeared. 
I guess `stop` is not supposed to act that way so I will just try to avoid to use it stand alone again =)